# How to export keymap Rider in Visual Studio?

Tags: export, settings, rider, keymapping

At the new job, everyone uses Visual Studio, but before that I worked in Rider and I want to transfer Keymap to Visual Studio. I'm using VS on win10.

Comment: Do you have created custom keyboard shortcuts? If not, which keyboard shortcuts are missing when using R# in Visual Studio?

Comment: @mu88 I just want to export the shortcuts from the ToolWindow section in the Rider, but as I understand it, there is no export to another IDE.

Comment: Nope, that's not possible as far as I know

Comment: that is unfortunate, I wanted to try VS to see what changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as [mu88](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4919526/mu88) replied, it is impossible.

Comment: Instead of providing the answer directly, try writing a comment explaining the solution if it's not too lengthy. @Max.